# Same dataset-/filter-logic on different models in sequel (DRY)

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel

I am building a sinatra web app with a sequel database backend. The primary tasks of this app is collecting status messages from different robots, store them in a database and provide various methods to view them. A common denominator in these messages is, that they provide a WGS84 position in lat/lon.

Now I want to provide various filters for querying messages based on their positions, but I want to write these filters only once, test them only once but re-use them in all model-classes with a lat/lon entry.

To boil it down to a very simple example:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table(:auvmessages) do
        primary_key :id
        Float       :lat
        Float       :lon
        String      :message
    end

    create_table(:asvmessages) do
        primary_key :id
        Float       :lat
        Float       :lon
        Integer     :chargestate
    end
  end
end

class Auvessage < Sequel::Model
  dataset_module do
    def north_of(lat)
        self.where{ latitude > lat}
    end
  end
end

class Asvessage < Sequel::Model
  dataset_module do
    def north_of(lat)
        self.where{ latitude > lat}
    end
  end
end
```

In both model classes have `north_of(lat)` to filter for messages which originate north of a given latitude. This function is fairly simple and you can easily repeat it two or three times, but what about more complex cases?

I have played around a bit with modules outside of `dataset_module` but nothing seem to be right.

Is there a preferred way how to re-use filters over different models? I have searched a lot, but didn't find any satisfying answer.

**Edit:**

To make my question a bit more precise: I want to move all functions like `north_of(lat)` (there are a *lot* more) into a service class. What I want to know now, is the best way to integrate that service class into a sequel-model:

- "Just" include it?
- Extend dataset_module, and if so, how?
- Writing a dataset-plugin?
- ...

Comment: I tried to clarify the question a bit more. A good night of sleep and @Gaston answer made it pretty obvious, that I didn't make myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an existing module to `dataset_module`:

```
module NorthOf
  def north_of(lat)
    where{latitude > lat}
  end
end
Auvessage.dataset_module NorthOf
Asvessage.dataset_module NorthOf
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Uncle Bob's [Screaming Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2011/09/30/Screaming-Architecture.html) blog post which might be of help.

Now, answering your question, it seems that `north_of`, as well as many other methods, are actually part of your domain logic. This logic should not go in persistence abstractions, or controllers, or views, etc.

Design, build and write tests for the set of objects that solves your problem in the language of the domain of your problem. Then, you'll have at hand a rich set of functionality that you can simply use on `Model`s, `Controller`s, CLIs, etc.

I usually put my service objects in a `lib/` directory and write simple unit tests, without any of the persistence boilerplate that sets up test databases. They usually run very fast as well.

Comment: What you described was exactly, what I wan to do. My question was more on the _how_ for the specific case of sequel models. But I didn't write that...

But nevertheless thanks for the link to the blog post, it was a good read!

Comment: I'm glad you liked the blog post. It helped me a lot to improve my architecture while working with frameworks. We tend to fall into what a framework tells us to do, forgetting to work on the design of the solution itself. At first it doesn't really matter, but once the codebase grows, it's critical to have a well designed domain logic. If you have more time, I would also recommend "Growing Object Oriented Programming Guided By Tests". Here are my notes: https://medium.com/books-read-by-gaston/growing-object-oriented-software-guided-by-tests-by-steve-freeman-and-nat-pryce-9c6deee0bc41

Answer (score 1):

As a followup: I have taken @jeremy-evans [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43474968/5854876) and extended it by a parametrisation scheme for modules. So from now on I can test my filters by mocking and my model classes have just a list of includes in their dataset_module.

I like it.

As explanation my slightly modified example:

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    create_table(:auvmessages) do
        primary_key :id
        Float       :lat
        Float       :lon
        String      :message
    end

    create_table(:asvmessages) do
        primary_key :id
        Float       :gps_lat
        Float       :gps_lon
        Integer     :chargestate
    end
  end
end

module GPSFilter
    def self.create(lat_name, lon_name)
        Module.new do
            include GPS

            define_method :lat_col_name do
                lat_name
            end

            define_method :lon_col_name do
                lon_name
            end
       end
    end

    def north_of(lat)
        where( "#{lat_col_name} > #{lat}" )
    end

    ##### default parameters #####
    def lon_col_name
        "lon"
    end

    def lat_col_name
        "lat"
    end
end

class Auvmessage < Sequel::Model
  dataset_module do
     include GPSFilter
  end
end

class Asvmessage < Sequel::Model
  dataset_module do
     include GPSFilter.create :gps_lat, :gps_lon
  end
end
```